# Websphere MQ Back-out queue configuration

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have DMLC listener that listens to messages from Websphere MQ 7.5.0.2. When there is a poison message, i wish to put it in the back-out Q after the retry count in MQ expires.

I have configured the back-out queue on the MQ, with the threshold value at 3.

However, what actually happens wen i throw an exception on the listener, the message is still being redelivered way more than 3 times and the the message goes back to the same queue every time and the cycle is repeated continuously.
The back-out threshold increases in MQ, but never the message never goes to the back-out Queue.

Am i missing something somewhere?What should i do if i want the message to be put in the back-out Queue.
Referring to the official docs below, there isn't any additional configuration for this.

[Websphere Poison Message Handling](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032280_.htm)

Is there any additional configurations that I need to do ?

Queue Details

```
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.   (This is the Source Queue)
   QUEUE(Q3)                               TYPE(QLOCAL)
   ACCTQ(QMGR)                             ALTDATE(2020-03-12)
   ALTTIME(22.16.44)                       BOQNAME(ORANGE.LOCAL.QUEUE)
   BOTHRESH(4)                             CLUSNL( )
   CLUSTER( )                              CLCHNAME( )
   CLWLPRTY(0)                             CLWLRANK(0)
   CLWLUSEQ(QMGR)                          CRDATE(2019-09-16)
   CRTIME(15.22.49)                        CURDEPTH(2)
   CUSTOM( )                               DEFBIND(OPEN)
   DEFPRTY(0)                              DEFPSIST(NO)
   DEFPRESP(SYNC)                          DEFREADA(NO)
   DEFSOPT(SHARED)                         DEFTYPE(PREDEFINED)
   DESCR( )                                DISTL(NO)
   GET(ENABLED)                            HARDENBO
   INITQ( )                                IPPROCS(0)
   MAXDEPTH(5000)                          MAXMSGL(4194304)
   MONQ(QMGR)                              MSGDLVSQ(PRIORITY)
   NOTRIGGER                               NPMCLASS(NORMAL)
   OPPROCS(0)                              PROCESS( )
   PUT(ENABLED)                            PROPCTL(COMPAT)
   QDEPTHHI(80)                            QDEPTHLO(20)
   QDPHIEV(DISABLED)                       QDPLOEV(DISABLED)
   QDPMAXEV(ENABLED)                       QSVCIEV(NONE)
   QSVCINT(999999999)                      RETINTVL(999999999)
   SCOPE(QMGR)                             SHARE
   STATQ(QMGR)                             TRIGDATA( )
   TRIGDPTH(1)                             TRIGMPRI(0)
   TRIGTYPE(FIRST)                         USAGE(NORMAL)


AMQ8409: Display Queue details.     (This is the backout queue)
   QUEUE(ORANGE.LOCAL.QUEUE)               TYPE(QLOCAL)
   ACCTQ(QMGR)                             ALTDATE(2020-03-12)
   ALTTIME(21.27.17)                       BOQNAME( )
   BOTHRESH(0)                             CLUSNL( )
   CLUSTER( )                              CLCHNAME( )
   CLWLPRTY(0)                             CLWLRANK(0)
   CLWLUSEQ(QMGR)                          CRDATE(2020-03-12)
   CRTIME(21.27.17)                        CURDEPTH(0)
   CUSTOM( )                               DEFBIND(OPEN)
   DEFPRTY(0)                              DEFPSIST(NO)
   DEFPRESP(SYNC)                          DEFREADA(NO)
   DEFSOPT(SHARED)                         DEFTYPE(PREDEFINED)
   DESCR( )                                DISTL(NO)
   GET(ENABLED)                            HARDENBO
   INITQ( )                                IPPROCS(0)
   MAXDEPTH(5000)                          MAXMSGL(4194304)
   MONQ(QMGR)                              MSGDLVSQ(PRIORITY)
   NOTRIGGER                               NPMCLASS(NORMAL)
   OPPROCS(0)                              PROCESS( )
   PUT(ENABLED)                            PROPCTL(COMPAT)
   QDEPTHHI(80)                            QDEPTHLO(20)
   QDPHIEV(DISABLED)                       QDPLOEV(DISABLED)
   QDPMAXEV(ENABLED)                       QSVCIEV(NONE)
   QSVCINT(999999999)                      RETINTVL(999999999)
   SCOPE(QMGR)                             SHARE
   STATQ(QMGR)                             TRIGDATA( )
```

---

Queue Permissions

```
    AMQ8864: Display authority record details.
   PROFILE(Q3)                             ENTITY(useradmin@DT-MachineName)
   ENTTYPE(PRINCIPAL)                      OBJTYPE(QUEUE)
   AUTHLIST(BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT,PASSALL,PASSID,SET,SETALL,SETID)
AMQ8864: Display authority record details.
   PROFILE(Q3)                             ENTITY(mqm@DT-MachineName)
   ENTTYPE(GROUP)                          OBJTYPE(QUEUE)
   AUTHLIST(BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT,PASSALL,PASSID,SET,SETALL,SETID)
AMQ8864: Display authority record details.
   PROFILE(Q3)                             ENTITY(user@domainName)
   ENTTYPE(PRINCIPAL)                      OBJTYPE(QUEUE)
   AUTHLIST(BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT,PASSALL,PASSID,SET,SETALL,SETID)
AMQ8864: Display authority record details.
   PROFILE(Q3)                             ENTITY(user2@domainName)
   ENTTYPE(PRINCIPAL)                      OBJTYPE(QUEUE)
   AUTHLIST(BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT,PASSALL,PASSID,SET,SETALL,SETID)

AMQ8864: Display authority record details.
   PROFILE(ORANGE.LOCAL.QUEUE)             ENTITY(useradmin@DT-MachineName)
   ENTTYPE(PRINCIPAL)                      OBJTYPE(QUEUE)
   AUTHLIST(BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT,PASSALL,PASSID,SET,SETALL,SETID)
AMQ8864: Display authority record details.
   PROFILE(ORANGE.LOCAL.QUEUE)             ENTITY(mqm@DT-MachineName)
   ENTTYPE(GROUP)                          OBJTYPE(QUEUE)
   AUTHLIST(BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT,PASSALL,PASSID,SET,SETALL,SETID)
```

---

Queue Manager Permissions

```
   AMQ8864: Display authority record details.
   PROFILE(SELF)                           ENTITY(user@domainName)
   ENTTYPE(PRINCIPAL)                      OBJTYPE(QMGR)
   AUTHLIST(ALTUSR,CHG,CONNECT,DLT,DSP,INQ,SET,SETALL,SETID,SYSTEM)
AMQ8864: Display authority record details.
   PROFILE(@CLASS)                         ENTITY(user@domainName)
   ENTTYPE(PRINCIPAL)                      OBJTYPE(QMGR)
   AUTHLIST(NONE)
```

---

**The Following error is seen the AMQERR01.LOG**

```
    14-03-2020 00:18:01 - Process(7752.172) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(DT-MachineName) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(QM1)
                     
AMQ8077: Entity 'user@domainNname' has insufficient authority to access object
'ORANGE.LOCAL.QUEUE'.

EXPLANATION:
The specified entity is not authorized to access the required object. The
following requested permissions are unauthorized: put/passall
ACTION:
Ensure that the correct level of authority has been set for this entity against
the required object, or ensure that the entity is a member of a privileged
group. 
----- amqzfubn.c : 515 --------------------------------------------------------
14-03-2020 00:18:01 - Process(7752.172) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(DT-MachineName) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(QM1)
                     
AMQ8077: Entity 'user@domainNname' has insufficient authority to access object
'DLQ'.

EXPLANATION:
The specified entity is not authorized to access the required object. The
following requested permissions are unauthorized: put/passall
ACTION:
Ensure that the correct level of authority has been set for this entity against
the required object, or ensure that the entity is a member of a privileged
group.
```

Comment: It would help if you can post the queue attributes. Use DIS QL(<your queue>) runmqsc command to dump the attributes.

Comment: @Shashi Added Queue Attributes.

Comment: BOQNAME and BOTHRESH Attributes look fine. MQ 7.5 is out of support. My suggestion would be try with latest fix pack of MQ v8/v9. You can try first by updating the MQ client only,

Comment: Does the user have `PASSALL` permission to the queue manager and backout queue?   Check the queue manager `AMQERR01.LOG` for an error related to permissions.

Comment: Does your application have the rights to put a message on the backout queue? You can see this for example with `dis authrec profile(ORANGE.LOCAL.QUEUE) objtype(QUEUE)`.

Comment: Another thing: The BOQNAME and BOTHRESH information is cached by the IBM MQ JMS classes. In case you change the queue attributes you have to restart your JMS application.

Comment: Resending please respond to what you missed.  Does the user have PASSALL permission to the **queue manager** and backout queue? **Check the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG for an error related to permissions.**

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks for pointing me to the AMQERR01.LOG file. I have found an error in the log and addedit to the question.

Comment: Please check for another error before that.

Comment: Provide permissions for the Q3 as well a QMGR itself.

Comment: @JoshMc Updated error stack, Q3 permissions added. How can i get the permissions for the QMGR
I have tried using  `dis authrec profile(QM1) objtype(QMGR)`

Comment: `DIS AUTHREC ALL OBJTYPE(QMGR) PRINCIPAL('user@domainNname')`

Comment: @JoshMc Updated Queue Manager Permissiosn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key error you have provided from the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` is below:

```
AMQ8077: Entity 'user@domainNname' has insufficient authority to access object
'ORANGE.LOCAL.QUEUE'.

EXPLANATION:
The specified entity is not authorized to access the required object. The
following requested permissions are unauthorized: put/passall
```

Based on the error provided, the user which is attempting to access the back out queue is `user@domainNname`.

From all of the information provided it appears that `user@domainNname` is only missing permissions to `ORANGE.LOCAL.QUEUE`, the following command should add the require permissions:

```
SET AUTHREC PROFILE(ORANGE.LOCAL.QUEUE) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) PRINCIPAL('user@domainNname') AUTHADD(PUT,PASSALL)
```

---

Note that back out queue processing in JMS will first attempt to use the specified `BOQNAME` for the queue that is being consumed from, if it is unable to open or put to this queue for any reason such as permission error, or queue full, it will then attempt to put to the queue manager's dead letter queue. This is why you also see an error in your logs stating `insufficient authority to access object 'DLQ'`.

Comment: It Worked!! Thanks so much. 
Though I have do have a question. Where can I get more troubleshooting for Websphere  MQ like these. All I could find was the official doc using which doesnt have any references to troubleshooting. 
But this was real good help. Thanks again.

Comment: I did remove my reference to `PASSALL` for the queue manager, this actually not a valid permission for the queue  manager.  There is another queue level permissions `SETALL` which does requires the same `SETALL` permission on the queue manager, `PASSALL` however is only valid at the queue level and not require on the queue manager or valid on the queue manager.

Comment: The key to me is to look at your error log.  The error said exactly what was wrong `AMQ8077: Entity 'user@domainNname' has insufficient authority to access object 'ORANGE.LOCAL.QUEUE'. The following requested permissions are unauthorized: put/passall`.  Also note that the way JMS Backout processing works is that it will first attempt to put to the `BOQNAME` specified on the queue you are consuming from.  If it is unable to open this queue for any reason it will them attempt to use the queue managers dead letter queue, this can be viewed with `DIS QMGR DEADQ`, in your case it is `DLQ`.

Comment: Yes, logs are the key here. First time working on this MQ. Thought once I configured the BO queue on the MQ, it will just work. I was thinking i missed something. Thanks for pointing out the log file though.

Comment: I have updated my question to hopefully be more clear and provide some additional details.

Comment: @frewper - first port of call with MQ for troubleshooting is always the AMQERR01.LOG. This will then give you an error message number to look up in Knowledge Center (and a general web search on the number is often also helpful).